# How to immediately return Server Sent Events from Mono.zip?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor

In the following example, I would expect the endpoint to emit `Server Sent Events` directly, or at least after 1-2 seconds.

But in fact, first all 1000 pages are aggregated, and then the events are emitted.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<JSONObject> test(Integer pages) {
    int pages = 1000; //for showcase
    return Flux.range(0, pages)
            .map(pageNumber -> Arrays.asList(1 * pageNumber, 2 * pageNumber, 3 * pageNumber))
            .flatMap(numbers -> Mono.zip(a(numbers), b(numbers)))
            .map(tuple -> {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("test", tuple);
                return json;
            });
}
```

Question: what would I have to change to get instant events after **each page** completion?

Interestingly, if I remove the `.flatMap(zip...)` line and add a sleep command inside the final `.map()` method, I'm directly receiving an event each 100ms:

```
 Flux.range(0, pages)
        .map(pageNumber -> Arrays.asList(1 * pageNumber, 2 * pageNumber, 3 * pageNumber))
        .map(tuple -> {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100); //direct events each 100ms
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("test", tuple);
            return json;
        });
```

So that is my desired result, but how can I now add a nonblocking zip into it that runs multiple submethods in parallel, and aggregates the result (I think this is what zip is for)?

Sidenote: I know this example does not make sense in itself, it's just to demonstrate my problem of not getting the SSE directly after each page.

For the target of this question, the zipped methods don't matter, but to be complete:

```
    private Mono<String> a() {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100); //simulate slow service
            return "a";
        });
    }

    private Mono<String> b() {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> "b");
    }
```

Comment: `flatMap(numbers -> Mono.zip(a(numbers), b(numbers)))` this flatmap does not return what you expect. I suspect you expect this to return the result of the `Mono.zip` a tuple. But what it in fact returns is a `Mono<T>`.

Comment: Correct. So what could I do about it to return he tuple result instead? Apply flatMap on the Mono directly?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to chain on the `Mono.zip` to get this to work.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<JSONObject> test(Integer pages) {
    int pages = 1000;
    return Flux.range(0, pages)
        .map(pageNumber -> Arrays.asList(1 * pageNumber, 2 * pageNumber, 3 * pageNumber))
        .flatMap(numbers -> {
            return Mono.zip(a(numbers), b(numbers))).map(tuple -> {
               JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
               json.put("test", tuple);
               return json; 
            });
}
```

Comment: Does it matter if I'd be using `Mono.zip().map()` or `Flux.zip().flatMap()` here?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, I could use `Mono.zip()` to combine the values returned by `a()`and `b()`, or I could as well use `Flux.zip()`. Both are offered, but how do I decide which one to chose?

Comment: well your code is strange and i have no idea what the purpose of it is. What is a(numbers)?, What is b(numbers)?, the zipped methods you have declared in your original post arn't even correct. Read what they do. `Mono.zip` takes x numbers of publishers and will return a `Mono<tuple>` Flux.zip will take multiple publishers and return a `Flux<tuple>` do you want a a `Flux` or do you want a `Mono` you already know the difference between a `Flux` and a `Mono`
Explain what it is you want to do, the purpose of your code, then what is notworking as you expect, and what you want the outcome to become

Comment: please check the api ducumentation for `Mono` and `Flux` and realy learn to understand what `static <T1,T2> Flux<Tuple2<T1,T2>> zip(Publisher<? extends T1> source1, Publisher<? extends T2> source2)` means

Comment: Ok I should have been more expressive with my method names. The methods that should be zipped in real world are blocking jdbc-selects. As I want to parallelize the selects (long running), I'd like to zip them. From this perspective, would the blocking processing more be a `Mono` (that emits the list of rows as one element), or a data publisher `Flux` that emits the rows as a list?

Comment: I dont know, a `Mono` is 0 or 1 results, a `Flux` is 0...n results. What you are asking me is "should i return one parameter or should i return a list" and my answer to you is write a full question with the 2 code examples that you are wondering about with real expressive names state what you want to do, what your question is and what your problem is. i answered this question above and you want to have a discussion about it. thats not how stack overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

I have to add a `.range().subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())`, at least it works when using it. Though I don't know exactly why.